# Is there any way to include all the sheets without writing them all manually?

Tags: google-apps-script

Title says it all. Here's what I have so far.

```
    function autoSort() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  
  // assign each sheet
  var ws1 = ss.getSheetByName("September")
  var ws2 = ss.getSheetByName("October")
  var ws3 = ss.getSheetByName("November")
  var ws4 = ss.getSheetByName("December")


  // range to be sorted
  var range1 = ws1.getRange(3,1, ws1.getLastRow()-2,6)
  var range2 = ws2.getRange(3,1, ws2.getLastRow()-2,6)
  var range3 = ws3.getRange(3,1, ws3.getLastRow()-2,6)
  var range4 = ws4.getRange(3,1, ws4.getLastRow()-2,6)

 // sort
  range1.sort({column: 6, ascending: true})
  range2.sort({column: 6, ascending: true})
  range3.sort({column: 6, ascending: true})
  range4.sort({column: 6, ascending: true})

  
}
```

Adding more sheets (Months) would mean having to manually write it again. I hope someone can help me with this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

sure, you can process them one at a time

```
var sheets = ss.getSheets();  
for (var x = 0; x < sheets.length; x++) {        
   var sheet = sheets[x];
   sheet.getRange(3,1, ws1.getLastRow()-2,6).sort(6);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function autoSort() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets().forEach(s => {
    s.getRange(3, 1, s.getLastRow() - 2, 6).sort({ column: 6, ascending: true })
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the other answers are good, but below is how to exclude certain worksheets or if there's a specific list of worksheets to run the procedure on.

```
function autoSortOnMonth() {
  const runThese = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length;i++) {
    var aSheet = allSheets[i];
    if (runThese.includes(aSheet.getName())) {
      var range = aSheet.getRange(3, 1, aSheet.getLastRow() - 2, 6)
      range.sort({ column: 6, ascending: true })
    }
  }
}


function autoSortAllButThese() {
  const skipThese = ["Admin Page", "FebTober"];
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var allSheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < allSheets.length;i++) {
    var aSheet = allSheets[i];

    //rule will run on all sheets unless in this 
    if (!skipThese.includes(aSheet.getName())) {
      var range = aSheet.getRange(3, 1, aSheet.getLastRow() - 2, 6)
      range.sort({ column: 6, ascending: true })
    }
  }
}
```